# How do you create a hyperlink in ASP.NET Core database to download files from a directory?

Tags: database, asp.net-core, hyperlink

What I would like to do is have a stored file path in a database that appears as a hyperlink and if clicked, it starts a download. In the future I would want to store multiple different file paths in database, and show them in a gridview.

I tried something like this - in the database, `Downloads` table, path:

```
<a href="~\wwwroot\Contents\sample.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

but this doesn't work as it cannot find file location.

Is it even possible doing it like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need to include the `wwwroot` in the href, using `href="/Contents/sample.pdf"` should work for you. remember, ASP.NET Core uses **wwwroot** folder by default when resolving static files (CSS, JS, Images etc), so using ~\wwwroot\Contents\sample.pdf essentially means looking for wwwroot sub folder inside wwwroot foler. Let's say the project is located at D:\dev\xyx, .net core will be looking for **d:\dev\xyx\wwwroot\wwwroot\Contents\sample.pdf** which is not correct (pay attention to the double wwwroot). the correct path should be **d:\dev\xyx\wwwroot\Contents\sample.pdf**

Second, you should never store the absolute file paths in the database, this is not a good practice. Save paths relative to your download folder in the database and then resolve them on the fly (dynamically) when rendering a tag.

Comment: It works, thank you!

Comment: Happy to help you!